# VBA writing data to an Access database

Tags: database, vba

I am getting an error that says

> Syntax error in insert into statement

How do resolve this error?

My code is:

```
 filePath = 1

 For filePath = 1 To 48
    Row = 6
    openFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\data\" & filePath & ".xls"
    Workbooks.Open (openFile)

    Sql = "insert into crimedata(reportYear, state, school, campus, dataLabel, dataValue) values(2011,'<S>','<U>',NULL,'<L>','<V>')"

    Sql = Replace(Sql, "<S>", Cells(2, 1).Value)

    Do Until Cells(Row, 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = 1
        Sql = Replace(Sql, "<U>", Cells(Row, 1).Value)
        Sql = Replace(Sql, "NULL", Cells(Row, 2).Value)
        ColumnCounter = 3

        Do Until ColumnCounter = 14

            Sql = Replace(Sql, "<L>", Cells(5, ColumnCounter).Value)
            Sql = Replace(Sql, "<V>", Cells(Row, 3).Value)
            cn.Execute Sql
```

I am receiving the error at the last line of code, `cn.execute Sql`.

Comment: Add a line `Debug.Print SQL` before the `Execute`.  Does the SQL look correct?  Note you can't do the replace in a loop like that: once you've replaced (eg) `<U>` with something, it's no longer there to be replaced the next time through the loop.

Comment: debug.print returns this: 

insert into crimedata(reportYear, state, school, campus, dataLabel, dataValue) values(2011,'ALABAMA1','Alabama A&M University',,'Student
enrollment2','5814')

which is the data I want.. but it wont write it to the access database

Comment: You need to either add a `null` for `campus`, or take that out of the field list.  Not sure why you're replacing the existing Null in the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim wb as Workbook, sht as worksheet
Const SQL_TEMPLATE As String = "insert into crimedata(reportYear, state, school, campus, " & _ 
                            " dataLabel, dataValue) values(2011,'<S>','<U>',NULL,'<L>','<V>')"

filePath = 1

For filePath = 1 To 48
    Row = 6
    openFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\data\" & filePath & ".xls"
    Set wb  = Workbooks.Open(openFile)
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(1)


    Do Until sht.Cells(Row, 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = 1

        ColumnCounter = 3

        Do Until ColumnCounter = 14

            Sql = Replace(SQL_TEMPLATE , "<S>", sht.Cells(2, 1).Value)
            Sql = Replace(Sql, "<U>", sht.Cells(Row, 1).Value)
            Sql = Replace(Sql, "NULL", sht.Cells(Row, 2).Value)
            Sql = Replace(Sql, "<L>", sht.Cells(5, ColumnCounter).Value)
            Sql = Replace(Sql, "<V>", sht.Cells(Row, 3).Value)
            cn.Execute Sql
```